# Is there a function to set a minimum size for symbols in tmap?

Tags: r, leaflet, tmap

when `tm_bubbles` or `tm_symbols` is used to create bubbles or dots representing my data, categorized using `size="data column of my choice"`, I am encountering a problem, where very small numbers in my dataset (let's say n=2 and my range is 10,2000), my bubble that represents x1=2000 is very visible on the screen, but x2=10 is so small that I can hardly see it on the screen. what I need is a function that sets a `size.minimum` for the bubbles. has anyone found a workaround for this problem? or can we create something like a `size.minimum` function for symbols?

Comment: Would the use of a logarithmic scale solve your problem?

Comment: @mgrund I'm not sure that would change anything because the smallest value in the dataset would still be assigned the smallest symbol size. Were you thinking of using a logarithmic scale with the `scale` function?

Comment: See my answer in which I show the difference with and without a logarithmic scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it currently looks like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(sf)
data("World")

df_dummy <- tibble(size = c(10, 200, 2000), 
                   points = c(st_sfc(st_point(c(-30,20))), 
                              st_sfc(st_point(c(7,52))),
                              st_sfc(st_point(c(30,5))))) %>% 
  st_as_sf()

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_fill(col = "gray") +
tm_shape(df_dummy) +
  tm_bubbles(col = "red",
             size = "size")
```

[image]

##### Option 1

If you now add a `` df_dummy`<- df_dummy %>% mutate(size = log10(size)) `` your data is scaled differenty since we use the log10 function. Of course you loose the information about the "original" values in the legend but all symbols are visible:

[image]

##### Option 2

Alternatively, you could simply generate a new column in which all values below a defined limit receive a specific size value (e.g. all values below 100 receive a size of 100). By this all values below this limit would be clipped to a single one which then can be used as your size parameter. In the following example the points with original sizes of 10, 50 and 80 are uniformly plotted with a clip size of 100. In the custom legend they are covered by the label <= 100.

```
df_dummy <- tibble(size = c(10, 50, 80, 500, 2000), 
                   points = c(st_sfc(st_point(c(-30,20))), 
                              st_sfc(st_point(c(7,52))),
                              st_sfc(st_point(c(10,45))),
                              st_sfc(st_point(c(15,35))),
                              st_sfc(st_point(c(30,5))))) %>% 
  mutate(size = ifelse(size <= 100, 100, size)) %>% 
  st_as_sf()

# see the tm_bubbles docs regarding the applied scaling
bubble_sizes <- ((c(100, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000)) / 2000) ^ 0.5 * 2 

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_fill(col = "gray") +
tm_shape(df_dummy) +
  tm_bubbles(col = "red",
             size = "size",
             scale = 2,
             border.col = "black",
             legend.size.show = F,  
                 legend.col.show = F) +
  tm_add_legend("symbol",
                size = bubble_sizes,
                col = "red",
                labels = c("<= 100","500","1000","1500", "2000"),
                title = "custom legend")
```

[image]

Comment: This solution does help with better representing/viewing symbols on the map, however it is really important for me that the legend still legibly shows the values used to calculate the symbol sizes.

Comment: I updated my post, see the last option which should almost fit what you want.

Comment: I think that this is the best option based on what is possible though it would be cool if there was a way to have the legend items represent the whole breadth of my values without compromising on the visibility of the smallest bubbles.

Comment: You may open a feature request PR in the tmap repo on GitHub addressing your issue.

Comment: What legend items do you want to see @BrendaThompson? Do you mean the exact sizes of the bubbles in the map? Or do you just want to increase the size of the smallest bubble in the map? Wanting to make sure everything is covered in the upcoming tmap4.

Comment: @MartijnTennekes I want to be able to set a minimum size for bubbles, just like I can set a max size. So for example if my range of values is (25,100), and let's say my values are c(25, 50, 75, 100), and I want my legend to have equal breaks, I'd end up with a legend with four bubbles, each representing my values. I would set my minimum bubble size to size=2, and my max size to size=8. So, my largest value (100) would assume a size of 8, and my smallest value (25) would assume a  size of 2. And any values smaller than 25 would also assume a size of 2.